# Group multi record CSV to JSON conversion

Tags: apache-nifi

I have below sample CSV data coming in multi record format. I want to convert to JSON format like below. I am using Nifi 1.8.

CSV:

```
id,name,category,status,country
1,XXX,ABC,Active,USA
1,XXX,DEF,Active,HKG
1,XXX,XYZ,Active,USA
```

Expected JSON:

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "status":"Active",
    "name":[
        "ABC",
        "DEF",
        "XYZ"
    ],
    "country":[
        "USA",
        "HKG"
    ]

}
```

I tried FetchFile -> ConvertRecord but it is converting every csv record to one JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal way would be using [QueryRecord](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/121794/running-sql-on-flowfiles-using-queryrecord-process.html) processor to run [Apache calcite SQL](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html) query to **`group by`** and **`collect`** as set to get your desired output.

But i don't know what exactly functions we can use in Apache calcite :(

***`(or)`***

You can store the data into **`HDFS`** then create a `temporary/staging` table on top of the hdfs directory.

Use **`SelectHiveQL`** processor run the below query:

```
select to_json(
            named_struct(
                         'id',id,
                         'status',status,
                         'category',collect_set(category),
                         'country',collect_set(country)
                         )
               ) as jsn 
from <db_name>.<tab_name>
group by id,status
```

***`Will result output flowfile as:`***

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|jsn                                                                                |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"id":"1","status":"Active","category":["DEF","ABC","XYZ"],"country":["HKG","USA"]}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can **Remove header** by using csv header to `false` in case of csv output.